# set_field_upload - how to custom multi image upload in grocery_CRUD library on codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, grocery-crud

I need to upload multiple image from `grocery_CRUD` Library on codeigniter framework.

I need step by step process !

```
$crud->set_field_upload('image','assets/uploads/products');
$crud->callback_after_upload(array($this,'resize_after_upload'));
```

Now this is working as a single image upload only. Anybody please to help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try ***Grocery_Crud_Multiuploader*** library, I wrote long back, might help you, instructions are given in github, current library supports files as well as images

[grocery_crud_multiuploader](https://github.com/Akshay-Hegde/grocery_crud_multiuploader)

Load library like below

```
function __construct()
{
       parent::__construct();
       $this->load->database();
       $this->load->helper('url');
       $this->load->library('grocery_CRUD');
       $this->load->library('Grocery_CRUD_Multiuploader');
}
```

In controller function

```
public function multi_upload()
{
   $crud = new Grocery_CRUD_Multiuploader(); 
   $crud->set_table('content');
   $crud->where('state', 1);   
   ...
   ...
   $config = array(
        /* Destination directory */
        "path_to_directory" =>'assets/grocery_crud_multiuploader/GC_uploads/pictures/',

       /* Allowed upload type */
      "allowed_types" =>'gif|jpeg|jpg|png',

      /* Show allowed file types while editing ? */
      "show_allowed_types" => true,

     /* No file text */
     "no_file_text" =>'No Pictures',

     /* enable full path or not for anchor during list state */
     "enable_full_path" => false,

     /* Download button will appear during read state */
     "enable_download_button" => true,

     /* One can restrict this button for specific types...*/
    "download_allowed" => 'jpg'
  );

  $crud->new_multi_upload("image",$config);
  ...
  ...
  $output = $crud->render();
  $this->_example_output($output);
}
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you

Comment: but this code view only for text box not a field field not showing!

Comment: Please elaborate your problem, did you try this library ?

Comment: $crud_image->new_multi_upload("image",$config);
                        //$crud->set_field_upload('image','assets/uploads/products');
   //$crud->callback_after_upload(array($this,'resize_after_upload'));

Comment: it is just showing the text box only not a file field?

Comment: beginning the functions. `$this->load->library('ajax_grocery_CRUD');
$this->load->library('Grocery_CRUD_Multiuploader');
$crud = new ajax_grocery_CRUD();
$crud_image = new Grocery_CRUD_Multiuploader(); 
$crud_image->set_table('product'); 
$crud_image->fields('image');
`

Comment: Please go through github, and read this [file](https://github.com/Akshay-Hegde/grocery_crud_multiuploader/blob/master/application/controllers/multiuploader.php), grocery crud doesn't support multiple upload, its custom library, please follow github instructions,