# Grocery Crud with Image Crud

Tags: codeigniter, file-upload, grocery-crud

I've grocery crud on my system and I want to use Image crud with groceryCrud for multiple file upload.
I've two tables attraction and attraction_images.

attractions ------> id , title, description
attraction_images -----> attraction_id,attraction_image

```
public function attraction()
{
   try{
        $crud = new grocery_CRUD();
        $crud->set_theme('datatables');
        $crud->set_table('attractions');
        $crud->set_subject('Attraction');
        $crud->required_fields('title');
        $crud->field_type('description', 'text');
        $crud->columns('title','description','image');

        $crud->callback_before_insert(array($this,'remove_special_char'));
        $crud->set_field_upload('image','assets/uploads/files');

        $crud->callback_column('image', array($this, 'callback_images'));

        $output = $crud->render();

        $this->_example_output($output);

        }catch(Exception $e){
            show_error($e->getMessage().' --- '.$e->getTraceAsString());
        }
    }
}

public function callback_images($value, $row)
{
     $html = '<div>';
     $attraction= $this->db->get_where('attraction_images',array('attraction_id' => $row->id))->result_array();
     if($attraction)
     {
       foreach ($attraction as $items)
       {
           $html.='<img src="'.base_url().'assets/uploads/files/'.$items['image'].'" style="width:200px;height:100px;"/>';
       }
     }
     $html.='</div>';
     return $html;
}
```

Now when user want to add an attraction I want imageCrud uploadImage button Option so that he could add multiple image for single attraction and insert those images path to attraction_images table.
I'm newbie to ImageCrud If any buddy could please help me out.

Thanks

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30523528/set-field-upload-how-to-custom-multi-image-upload-in-grocery-crud-library-on-c) may help you,  grocery_crud doesn't support multiple upload at present