# Multiple upload of Grocery CRUD does not work

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload, multi-upload

I need to upload multiple image, i read a lot of documentation that do not work, and I see this:

[Link to the question: set_field_upload - how to custom multi image upload in grocery_CRUD library on codeigniter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30523528/set-field-upload-how-to-custom-multi-image-upload-in-grocery-crud-library-on-c)

I made all what they said and, when I call in my view their controller "multiuploader" it works all fine, but, when I use in my own controller does not work. It saves images into the database and in the folder, but I can not see anything in the form, like the images in add, or the links in the list, even when i save in the same table before with the "multiuploader".

I apreciate a lot if you can help me. Thanks in advance.

This is my controller.

```
public function Test() {

            $this->crud = new Grocery_CRUD_Multiuploader();
            $this->crud->set_table('multi_uploader_gallery');
            $this->crud->set_subject('Document');
            $this->crud->fields("title", "my_pictures", "my_files", "my_mail_attachments");
            $this->crud->columns("title", "my_pictures", "my_files", "my_mail_attachments");

$config = array(
                /* Destination directory */
                "path_to_directory" => 'assets/test',
                /* Allowed upload type */
                "allowed_types" => 'gif|jpeg|jpg|png',
                /* Show allowed file types while editing ? */
                "show_allowed_types" => true,
                /* No file text */
                "no_file_text" => 'No Pictures',
                /* enable full path or not for anchor during list state */
                "enable_full_path" => false,
                /* Download button will appear during read state */
                "enable_download_button" => true,
                /* One can restrict this button for specific types... */
                "download_allowed" => 'jpg'
            );

            $this->crud->new_multi_upload("my_pictures", $config);

            $output = $this->crud->render();
            $data['contents'] = 'contents';
            $data = array_merge($data, (array) $output); 
            $this->load->view('template', $data);
        }
```

[in the view (add)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIfOJ.jpg)

when I use my view but the example table do not show any errors, but when I use my table it shows this:

[error in my view with the view (list)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfoUt.jpg)

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Have you looked at the error log?

Comment: in the view i don't see any errors. Where I looking for the error log?

Comment: when I use my view but the example table do not show any errors, but when I use my table it shows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the error, I do not put a **/** in the end of the path, and give me all those problems

```
"path_to_directory" => 'assets/test/',
```

As for the previous errors I did different tests changing the name of the table and they simply disappeared.

Answer (score -1):

I got also this error and It is caused by old (not serialized) data already in the multi upload columns. You must serialize them or empty the field.